# Por quê os testes if ou case não funcionam nessa subquery?

Tags: mysql, query, if, case

Estou tentando executar a seguinte subquery dentro de uma view:

```
    (SELECT 

        if(idnotas > 0, "não", "sim")

    FROM notas WHERE vendas_idvendas = p.vendas_idvendas
    ORDER BY idnotas DESC
    LIMIT 1

    )  as primeiraFatura,
```

Porém, o if só é definido quando a condição é verdadeira.
No momento em que ela é falsa, eu recebo um null, ao invés do sim.

O engraçado é que se eu executo o mesmo como uma query normal ( sem ser uma subquery ) o retorno é exatamente o que eu quero, e o valor "sim" é atribuído ( quando corresponde a condição ).

Segue a query completa:

```
         SELECT 

    idpatrimonios, numeroPatrimonio, n.dataVencimento,

    (SELECT nomeTipo FROM tipos WHERE idtipos = p.tipos_idtipos) as tipo,

    cl.idclientes as idclientes, p.vendas_idvendas, dataEntrega, dataFatura,

    (
        SELECT 

            if(idnotas > 0, "não", "sim")

        FROM notas WHERE vendas_idvendas = p.vendas_idvendas
        ORDER BY idnotas DESC
        LIMIT 1

    )  as primeiraFatura,

    (
        SELECT 

            case 
                WHEN MONTH(dataVencimento) >= MONTH(NOW()) THEN "não"
                WHEN NOW() >= dataFatura THEN "sim"
            end

        FROM notas WHERE vendas_idvendas = p.vendas_idvendas
        ORDER BY idnotas DESC
        LIMIT 1

    )  as exibirNaLista

FROM patrimonios as p

INNER JOIN vendas as v ON v.idvendas = p.vendas_idvendas
INNER JOIN clientes as cl ON cl.idclientes = v.clientes_idclientes
LEFT JOIN logpatrimonios as log ON log.patrimonios_idpatrimonios = p.idpatrimonios
LEFT JOIN notas as n ON n.vendas_idvendas = p.vendas_idvendas 

WHERE situacao_idsituacao = 2 

group by idpatrimonios;
```

Estou usando o Mysql 8.

Comment: ja tentou usar aspas simples :

Comment: Sim, não é o problema.

Comment: Se calhar será melhor validar se o campo é `NULL` e atribuir um valor: `if(ifnull(idnotas. 0) > 0, "não", "sim")`

Comment: Não me ajuda muito, mas testei só pra desencargo de consciência e o retorno continua sendo nulo: if(ifnull(idnotas, 0) > 0, "não", "sim")

Comment: SELECT IF(COUNT(idnotas) > 0, 'não', 'sim') FROM notas...

Comment: Fábio, dessa forma resolveu o problema.
Mas, ainda continuo com a questão em outros pontos da query que retornam null quando a primeira condição não é satisfeita, como por exemplo no retorno de 'exibirNaLista'. Preciso entender o que fazer com esses retornos null para que continuem os testes em caso da condição não ser satisfeta.

Comment: Vitor, a primeira condição?!? Desculpe, pergunta: Qual é a primeira condição? Seria "não"??

Comment: Vou considerar que você está me perguntando sobre o 'exibirNaLista'.

Tenho dois casos:

WHEN MONTH(dataVencimento) >= MONTH(NOW()) THEN 'não'
WHEN NOW() >= dataFatura THEN 'sim'

Se o mês da data de vencimento for maior ou igual ao mês da data atual, quero exibir o não. Até este ponto funciona perfeitamente. O problema acontece no caso do mês de vencimento ser menor que o mês atual, onde nunca entro no segundo caso, por alguma razão

Comment: Vitor, talvez seja o seguinte: As duas condições NÃO são satisfeitas.

Comment: Não é este o caso, Fabio. Conforme respondi seu comentário, mesmo colocando um ELSE, ainda recebo null. E, como descrito na pergunta, se eu executar a subquery individualmente, obtenho os dados que quero normalmente.

Comment: Vitor, olhei alguns exemplos na w3schools.com e estou achando que o "as exibirNaLista" está na posição errada... por favor, verifique.

Answer (score 0):

Vitor,

Por favor, use o ELSE, dessa forma: EXEMPLO (corrija a seu gosto):

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN MONTH(dataVencimento) >= MONTH(NOW()) THEN "não"
    WHEN NOW() >= dataFatura THEN "sim"
    ELSE "sim"
END
FROM ...
```

Comment: Ainda retorna null. A segunda condição está sendo satisfeita, a questão é que o a query só interpreta a primeira condição e, caso seja verdadeira, retorna seu valor. Caso contrário, retorna null, independente das demais condições a serem verificadas.

Answer (score 0):

Vitor,

Mude a posição do "exibirNaLista" para depois do "end", dessa forma:

```
(
SELECT 
case 
WHEN MONTH(dataVencimento) >= MONTH(NOW()) THEN "não"
WHEN NOW() >= dataFatura THEN "sim"
ELSE "sim"
end as exibirNaLista
FROM notas WHERE vendas_idvendas = p.vendas_idvendas
ORDER BY idnotas DESC
LIMIT 1
)
FROM patrimonios as p
...
```

Comment: Mesmo problema fazendo da forma acima.

Mas, fiz a query dessa forma:  

if(idnotas > 0, 
 if(MONTH(NOW() > MONTH(n.dataVencimento)), "sim", "não"), 
 if(NOW() >= v.dataFatura, "sim", "não")
) as exibirNaLista,

E obtenho os resultados que quero. O problema só acontece quando eu uso o if ou case dentro de um novo select, justamente onde mais preciso.

Comment: No StackOverFlow em inglês, tem uma pergunta parecida: "Can I use a subquery inside a case statement?" ... "acho que você tem uma outra questão, que é o que você está realizando uma agregação em uma expressão que contém uma subconsulta, que dá um erro."